# Map "Control" in Vim without secondary character?

Tags: vim

I can map a combination like `Ctrl+C` in vim like so:

`imap <C-c> <Esc>`

Is there any way to map *only* the Control key itself to another key? I want to use Control as Escape. `imap` only maps the key in Insert mode so I'm not losing much I care about.

I have tried:

- `imap <C> <Esc>`
- `imap <C-> <Esc>`

Nothing written in the docs on this that I could find with `:help keycodes`

Comment: There are many useful `<C-...>` combinations in insert mode; I wouldn't want to lose them. For example `:h i_CTRL-E` and `:h i_CTRL-r`.

Comment: i recommend remapping caps lock to escape. it's just useful everywhere.

Comment: @acushner Interestingly enough, I had mapped caps lock to Control, but perhaps that will work better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible within Vim. Modifier keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> cannot be mapped standalone. The reason is that in a terminal, these keypresses aren't sent to the application, only "full" ones are.

But you can do the remapping on the operating system level. These pages should give you the right pointers:

- [Map caps lock to escape in Windows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_Windows)
- [Map caps lock to escape in XWindows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows)

Comment: Thanks, that definitely makes sense after reading about how Vim uses byte sequences rather than key presses due to the terminal history.